# Highlight UICollectionViewCells with PanGesture using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm using the below code to track cells when a user drags their finger over them (this works great). That said, I want to highlight each of the cells (or change the color of the background view in my custom cells) as the user drags their finger over top of them. How can I accomplish this? See below.

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
    [self.ringCollectionView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
}


- (void) handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) panGesture
{
    CGPoint location = [panGesture locationInView:self.ringCollectionView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.ringCollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:location];
    NSMutableArray *selectedIndexes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.ringCollectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]];

    if (![selectedIndexes containsObject:@(indexPath.row)]) {

        NSLog(@"THIS CELL IS %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
    }
    else
        if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        }
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}


- (__kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"RingCollectionViewCell";
    RingCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}


- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Tapping");
}


- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(118, 118);
}
```

Comment: You aren't showing the data source of your collection view.

Comment: Why do you use gesture recognizer for tracking these cells instead of just working with delegate methods?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind I was under the impression that if I wanted to drag (and not just tap) over the collectionview cells, I'd need the gesture?

Comment: @ElTomato That's because there's currently no data in my cells. They're simply empty with a white background. Ie. I'm returning 10 blank cells.

Comment: Then how do you keep track of the tapped cells?

Comment: @ElTomato Hilariously I don't need to track just tapped cells for what I'm trying to accomplish here. Though if I did, then I'd do that in didSelectItemAtIndexPath. Is there a way to detect dragging over cells in didSelectItem?

Comment: You can't achieve on didselect.. Subclass your cell and do things inside.. you can simply add pan gesture in `self.contentView` and do stuffs.

Comment: Are you asking how to use a pan gesture to manipulate the background color or do you want to keep track of cells that have recognized a gesture?

Comment: @SeaSpell Both - but my current code already tracks the cells when they are dragged over (ie. when I drag my finger over cell 1, console logs 1 successfully) - now I just want to know how I can change the background color of the cell when it is recognized by the gesture :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I believe tracking selected cells via "native" `UICollectionView` mechanism is reasonable and consistent. There isn’t any need for custom gesture handlers inside of the cells. In order to represent selected state however, you need to set [`selectedBackgroundView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcell/1620138-selectedbackgroundview?language=objc) property, something like this:

```
- (__kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"RingCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell.selectedBackgroundView) {
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I don't know how your `RingCollectionViewCell` class is designed, but be advised that you will need to ensure `contentView` of this cell has transparent background color otherwise it will obscure the `selectedBackgroundView`.

Now the tricky part. `UIPanGestureRecognizer` gets events very quickly and the handle method will be called quite often when the user just keeps his/her fingers still on the screen. Thus you need to somehow suppress events which are not supposed to switch selected state of a cell.

My suggestion is to ignore all consequence events if they happen in the same cell. In order to implement such behavior we need to store index path of the last cell touched. Let’s use a simple property for that:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic, nullable) NSIndexPath *trackingCellIndexPath;

@end
```

Now you need to assign index path of last touched cell to this property in your gesture handle method. You also need to reset this property when the gesture is finished or cancelled. Switch selection of the given index path if it is not equal to the tracked index path and ignore the touch event otherwise:

```
- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    // Reset the tracking state when the gesture is finished
    switch (recognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
            self.trackingCellIndexPath = nil;
            return;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Obtain the cell the user is currently dragging over
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.collectionView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:location];

    // If the user currently doesn't touch any cell, reset the tracking state and prepare to listen to another cell
    if (!indexPath) {
        if (self.trackingCellIndexPath) {
            self.trackingCellIndexPath = nil;
        }
        return;
    }

    // If current event is subsequent gesture event which happens within the same cell, ignore it
    if (self.trackingCellIndexPath == indexPath) {
        return;
    }

    // If the cell hasn't been previously tracked, switch the selected state and start tracking it
    self.trackingCellIndexPath = indexPath;
    if ([self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    } else {
        [self.collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
    }
}
```

The last thing to change is the selection mode of the collection view. As you expect multiple cells to remain selected, just switch `allowsMultipleSelection` of your collection view somewhere in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
}
```

Comment: But what if I need to track multiple cells? Ie. if the user drags their finger over cells 0-5, I want all 5 to be highlighted (not just 1 cell at a time)?

Comment: @Brittany I think I start to understand: you don't need to highlight cells a user is currently dragging over but you need to highlight all cells he touched (and unhighlight if he touches them again) and keep them highlighted if the dragging gesture ends. I'm sorry I gave the answer without properly understanding the question, could you please confirm that this is a desired result?

Comment: Correct, that is exactly what I'm looking to do :)

Comment: This was mind-blowingly helpful, thank you SO much for revising your answer. It's exactly what I wanted to accomplish!

Answer (score 0):

So in order to change color you need to decide how to handle the gesture, but also how to change colors. Consider the following:

```objectivec
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat redColor;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat greenColor;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat blueColor;

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint startPoint;

@end

@implementation ViewController

// insuring reasonable values
-(void)setRedColor:(CGFloat)colorX {
    CGFloat x = colorX;
    x = x > 0 ? x : 0;
    x = x < 1.0 ? x : 1.0;
    _redColor = x;
}

-(void)setGreenColor:(CGFloat)colorY {
    CGFloat y = colorY;
    y = y > 0 ? y : 0;
    y = y < 1.0 ? y : 1.0;
    _greenColor = y;
}

- (void)setBlueColor:(CGFloat)colorZ {
    CGFloat z = colorZ;
    z = z > 0 ? z : 0;
    z = z < 1.0 ? z : 1.0;
    _blueColor = z;
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    
    UIView *panView = [UIView new];
    panView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor;
    
    panView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    
    [self.view addSubview:panView];
        
    [self.view addConstraints:@[
        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:panView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0],
        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:panView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0],
        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:panView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1 constant:0],
        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:panView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1 constant:0]
    ]];
    
    [panView addGestureRecognizer:[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action: @selector(handlePanGesture:)] ];
}
```

//Important Parts

```
-(void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) panGesture {

    //getting our position from super for total location area
    UIView *aView = [[panGesture view] superview];

    if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
         //saving the start of our pans point
        _startPoint = [panGesture translationInView: aView];
        
    }else if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        //where our pan moved
        //For this example I'm just using changed value to set color using CGFLoat, but you could also determine a direction and go through a UIcolor array or however you want to actually set your color.
        CGPoint trin = [panGesture translationInView:aView];
        
        CGFloat xInc = (trin.x - _startPoint.x);// find how much left or right the finger moved.
        CGFloat yInc = (trin.y - _startPoint.y); // find how much up or down the finger moved.
        CGFloat base = 1.0; //used to keep values in range
        
        //altering colors based on movement
        //just as an example for the color change. Ideally you would implement a better color scheme.
        [self setRedColor: self.redColor + (xInc == 0 ? 0 : base / xInc)];
        [self setGreenColor: self.greenColor + (yInc == 0 ? 0 : base / yInc)];
        self.blueColor =  self.greenColor + self.redColor;
    
        //setting the new color of our panView
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
                panGesture.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: self.redColor
                                                        green: self.greenColor
                                                         blue: self.blueColor
                                                        alpha:1.0];
            }];
            
        });
    } else if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        _startPoint = CGPointZero;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: note if xInc is not negative the gesture moved right and likewise if yInc is not negative the gesture is moving down. if either are 0 there is no movement  in that axis.

Comment: I'll give this a try, but it doesn't show me how to reference my custom collectionview cell inside the pan gesture?

Comment: In your case, pan gestures view is ringCollectionView, because that is the view who contains the gesture that is sending the message.

Comment: Yes, but this changes the color of the entire ringCollectionView? And not just of the cell recognizing the gesture inside the ringCollectionView?

Comment: In your code you add the recognizer the the cell [self.ringCollectionView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture]; RingCollectionViewCell is a subclass of UIView so this is legal. panGesture.view returns the view it was assigned to.  If you want another view to change you simply call the change on another view.? Are you calling it on its superview notice I change view when changing the color.

Comment: I get movement in [[panGesture view] superview]; but I change colors with panGesture.view.backgroundColor =

Comment: You said: "In your code you add the recognizer the the cell [self.ringCollectionView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture]; " -- but this is not adding the gesture to the cell, it's adding it to the entire collectionView. That said, when I add the gesture to the cell, it only changes the background color of 1 cell I'm dragging on at a time? Instead of allowing me to drag my finger across 5 cells and have it change the background color of all 5.

Comment: You're right I miss read that. So you are adding it to ringCollectionView. So you are correct it changes the cell when added to the cell that sends the gesture if you want to do more than one cell you are talking about multiple gestures I'm assuming??